# Spacing between label and input box

Tags: javascript, html, css

index.php

```
<div class="detail">
    <?php echo Form::label("first_name", "First Name"); ?>
    <?php echo Form::input("first_name", $userdetails->first_name); ?>
</div>
```

I am getting the output in the below format mentioned in image,i want some space between first name and input box.What css property i should apply.

[image]

tried this

```
.field { 

    margin-left:10px;
}

.field label {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: There are various combinations of margin and padding that should work. What have you tried?

Comment: I updated the tried code

Comment: With these type of questions it is always better to post your rendered markup not the php.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss has a good point, since this is a question about CSS and CSS doesn't interact with PHP, posting the HTML would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a CSS selector based on the parent `div.detail` element to give some margin between the elements:

```
.detail label {
     margin-right : 5px;
}
```

OR

```
.detail input {
     margin-left : 5px;
}
```

This is just two methods of many...

Answer (score 1):

put a margin on right side of label `margin-right:10px;`

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a padding such as `padding-right: XXpx;` to your label and you're good to go.